# The "ProduceIncludeFrameworksCommand" task was not given a value for the required parameter "XcodePath"

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin

I keep getting the following error in Visual studio for my Xamarin iOS Mobile project.

```
Error The "ProduceIncludeFrameworksCommand" task was not given a value for the required parameter "XcodePath". STARS.Mobile.iOS
```

However I cannot seems to find where to add this parameter. And there doesn't seems to be anything on the internet that is pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to downgrade your 'Xamarin.Swift' package.

You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.Swift/issues/49) for more details. If it doesn't work, you can open an issue by yourself.

From your Infos, it's problem with 'Xamarin.Swift' package, but the IDE can also cause this problem. So, if it still not work, you can try to reinstall Xcode and Visual Studio for Mac.